# Data Lake Gen2 Upgrade

Tags: azure, devops, storage, azure-data-lake

Good Morning,

I am having trouble upgrading a standard Azure storage account to Data Lake Gen2 Upgrade. I keep receiving this error in the validation process. “:Values for account properties are incompatible: containerDeleteRetentionPolicy.” What can I do to fix this? I am ultimately looking to setup a container to create a metastore.

I figured it was an issue with configuring the DNS server but I am still receiving the same error message.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but have you seen this documentation? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/upgrade-to-data-lake-storage-gen2

Answer (score 8):

I tried in my environment, and I got same error.

[image]

To resolve this error, make sure you disable the `Enable soft delete for blobs` and `Enable soft delete for containers`. To disable these, Go to **Data protection** of Blob storage, disable and click on save.

[image]

Check other [features](https://i.imgur.com/IbNdf6u.png) as well which are not supported by the upgrade process.

Now, start the process and your Blob storage account upgrade will be successful as mine.

[image]